# Running PowerShell command via Python gives an error

Tags: python, powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to run this `PowerShell` command via Python:

```
sid = utils.execute_powershell(settings.D01_DC1_PORT,
                               settings.D01_USER,
                               settings.PASSWORD,
                               '(Get-ADForest).Domains | '
                               '%{Get-ADDomain -Server $_}| '
                               'select domainsid')
```

The port, the user and the password are all valid. If I run the same script in PowerShell I see values.

Yet, via Python I get this error:

**'Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running.'**

What is wrong here?

Comment: You executing uisng os.sytem or subprocess?\

Comment: using os.system

Comment: like saving this snippet in `ps1` file ?..Instead try creating a batch file that executes ps1 file & run through `os.system`. Like `os.system('file.bat')`

Answer (score 0):

If I change my script so that only one row "returns" from the query, the code passes:

```
sid = utils.execute_powershell(settings.D01_DC1_PORT,
                               settings.D01_USER,
                               settings.PASSWORD,
                               '(Get-ADForest).Domains | '
                               '%{Get-ADDomain -Server $_}| '
                               'select domainsid -First 1')
```

Comment: @mklement0 No, it's not the same code. New script ends with -First 1

Comment: Was it case of `sid` needing to be a _single_ value, but your PowerShell command returned multiple results, and using the accidentally array-valued `sid` value caused a problem later, in code not being shown?

Comment: Yes, the issue is that my script returns 2 lines, not just a single line